# invalid use of incomplete type 'class classname' c++

Tags: c++, declaration, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

One.h

```
#pragma once
class Three;

class One
{
    public:
      std::string name;
      One(std::string newName);
      virtual void Myfunction(Three *three) = 0;
}
```

One.cpp

```
#include "One.h"

One::One(std::string newName)
{
      name = newName;
}
```

Two.h

```
#pragma once
#include "One.h"

class Two : public One
{
   public:
        Two(std::string newName);
        void Myfunction(Three * three);
}
```

Two.cpp

```
#include "Two.h"

Two::Two(std::string newName)
        :One(newName)
{};

void Two::Myfunction(Three *three)
{
    std::cout << three->newnum << std::endl;
}
```

Three.h

```
 #pragma once
 #include "One.h"

 class Three
 {
     public:
          One *one;
          int num;
          Three(One *newone, int newnum);
 }
```

Three.cpp

```
 #include "Three.h"

 Three(One *newone, int newnum)
     :one(newone),
      num(newnum)
 {     
 }
```

So I have three classes One which is parent of Two which Two overrides the purely virtual function. Three holds a pointer to One object which I want a point to Three in Two so I can use polymorphism when making more classes inherit from One to make One pointers equal to new objects that are children of One, and do for all those Objects print num from the three pointer. When I compile i get

> error:invaild use of incomplete type 'class Three' 
>   std::cout << three->num << std::endl;

I know I have circular dependency I'm just stuck on how to fix it.

Comment: Try, in `Two.cpp` -> `#include "Three.h"`

Comment: But you should still have the posted error as `Two.cpp` has not included `Three.h`